# Merging two Sql queries result side by side

Tags: mysql

I have page_no and title as my columns , so i want all of the page_no even number title to be on left side and odd numbers to be on right side.

This is how my data looks,

```
page_no title
1       abc
2       def
3       ghi
4       jkl
6       mno
```

output

```
left_title  right_title
Null        abc
def         ghi
jkl         null
mno         null
```

this is the query i had tried, i stuck on merging the two queries side by side.

```
with left_qry as
    (
    select 0 as page_no,Null as ttile
    union all
    SELECT * from recipes where cast(page_no as int) %2 = 0
    ),
    right_qry as
    (
    SELECT * from recipes where cast(page_no as int) %2 <> 0
    )
    -- here i am trying to merge left_qry and right_qry side by side
    select * from left_qry
    union 
    select * from right_qry;
```

can some one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not seriously advocating this as a solution, because I think this kind of thing is best resolved in application code... but just for fun...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(page_no INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,title CHAR(3) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'abc'),
(2,'def'),
(3,'ghi'),
(4,'jkl'),
(6,'mno');

WITH RECURSIVE cte (n) AS
(
  SELECT 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM cte WHERE n < (SELECT MAX(page_no) FROM my_table)
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN MOD(n,2)=0 THEN title END) L
     , MAX(CASE WHEN MOD(n,2)=1 THEN title END) R
  FROM cte
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table x
    ON x.page_no = n
 GROUP
    BY FLOOR(n/2);

+------+------+
| L    | R    |
+------+------+
| NULL | abc  |
| def  | ghi  |
| jkl  | NULL |
| mno  | NULL |
+------+------+
```

`MAX(page_no)` probably needs tweaking to allow for an odd max number of pages